# Re-Arranging $P(A\cap B^c\cap C^c)$ to be $P(B^c\cap C^c)-P(A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c)$

Tags: probability

[image]

Is there a method to this step or is does this come from experience? I can't intuitively tell how this makes sense though.

I tried using De Morgan's law to get $P(A\cap(B\cup C)^c)$ or $P((A\cup B\cup C)^c)=1-P(A\cup B\cup C)$. I then tried to use inclusion-exclusion as well but none of that worked.

I am also not sure what is meant by additivity. It was mentioned in a foot note of these lecture notes but I don't think what was said there was relevant.

---

I'll leave the footnote here just in case:

**Some comments on additivity** For a finite or countably infinite sample space additivity implies, by
forming a sequence from the sample points, that the probability of any event is the sum of the probabilities of
the sample points it contains. For an uncountably infinite sample space we cannot make the same argument
because we cannot make a sequence of all the sample points in a general event. Additivity for infinite sequences
of events is very useful in uncountable sample spaces though. For example it allows us to argue that the area
of a disc can be calculated by covering the disc with an infinite sequence of rectangles of decreasing size, and
computing the sum of their areas. As an example of additivity failing to hold we can consider the following
attempt to define probabilities:
$$P(A) = lim\,{n→∞}\frac{1}{n}
|A ∩ {1, 2, . . . , n}|$$
for any A ⊆ N for which the limit exists. This looks like it might define appropriate probabilities for choosing
a random number ‘uniformly from N’— but such a notion is not useful. Indeed, if we could define such an
idea, then if $B_i = {i}$, then $P(B_i) = P(B_j)$ for any $i, j$ (the probability is meant to be uniform). Specifically,
$P(B_i) = P(B_1)$. Suppose $P(B_1) = p > 0$. Then for some natural number $n$, additivity implies the probability
of the event that a number between $1$ and $n$ is selected must exceed $1$. (Eventually, $np > 1$ no matter how small
$p$ is.

Comment: Hint: $P(X\cap Y)=P(X)-P(X\cap Y')$

Comment: @DatBoi Thank you very much! Are there more of these identities? Where can I find them?

Comment: Almost all of these identities can be derived immediately using venn diagrams. Play around with it, you will come up with many by yourself! :P